# How do I search for all files a user has changed between 2 dates in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to start doing code reviews with my Peers and Im trying to fathom a system for doing them. I would like to know is it possible to perform a search of a tortoise svn repository for all the files that a user has committed between 2 dates? That way we can code review them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tortoise SVN has a Show Log option which you can use on a folder or file and then select date filters within the dialog that appears. You can also filter for particular authors too.

Click on each commit to show the files changed, then double click a file below to view the diff.